# Django: how to create a selection list of items from another table?

Tags: django, forms, post

I like to make a checkbox selection list from items from the another table.
So i have 2 models:

```
class ItemNames(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40, blank=False, null=False$

class UserSelectedItems(models.Model):
    auth_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    itemnames= models.OneToOneField(ItemNames)
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

ItemNames.names is filled like ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', ..., 'itemN']

I cannot figure out how to make a form where user can select items what he want with a check boxes. Like:

```
Select  | Items
  x     | item1
  x     | item2
 ...    |  ...
  x     | itemN
Submit
```

And after pressing submit form checkbox status data will be saved to UserSelectedItems.itemnames. (all items with a True/False data)

How to do this in 'nice' way?

Comment: I don't understand these models at all. Are you saying that one instance of ItemNames has a "name" attribute of "['item1', 'item2', 'item3', ..., 'itemN']"? Why? And why is there a one-to-one between UserSelectedItems and ItemNames?

Comment: As i'm noob with a SQL and django so it's likely my fault.
Basically ItemNames saves all items names what user can selected. Every item is own row in ItemNames table. That way i can easily edit item names and add new ones when it's needed.
One to one relation is there so i can easily get names of items what user have selected. idea is save a ItemNames primary key index to UserSelectedItems itemsnames field.